# Times font with polyglossia package

Tags: fonts, xetex, times

How to configure Times font to work with XeLaTeX's `polyglossia` package? I tried configuring it same as with PdfLaTeX, but this way does not work: **bold** and *italic*  are shown as normal font.

Minimal working example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{uhv}
\renewcommand{\rmdefault}{utm}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{ucr}

\begin{document}
    \textbf{Bold text} \textit{Italic text} Normal text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Polyglossia relies on `fontspec`. Can you give some more information about your operating system and TeX distribution?

Comment: `\setmainfont{Times New Roman}`, see the documentation of `fontspec` (loaded by polyglossia).

Comment: ```fontspec error: "font-not-found"``` - I do not have Times New Roman installed on my system, because its a propietary font. I hope that some kind of standard package supports this font for XeLaTeX.

Comment: You can use the clon tex gyre termes: `\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Termes}`. Imho times (or a clon) is available for every system (I certainly didn't buy it), but it could be that the name is different.

Comment: Is _Tex Gyre Termes_ font same as _Nim­bus Ro­man No9 L_ font? Found this idea [here](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tex-gyre-termes). I need to find differences between _TeX Gyre Termes_ and _Times New Roman_.

Comment: No, it is not the same. Termes is a more recent clone than Nimbus Roman No9. Nimbus Roman No9 is what you are (almost certainly) getting when you set the serif default as `utm` and use pdfLaTeX. @UlrikeFischer I think it is part of that set of fonts you can get free from MS, even if you aren't on Windows. It is proprietary, though, so it may not be available on every system even though it is in some sense available for every system. On most GNU/Linux boxes, you'll get a clone and I don't think `fontspec` respects `fontconfig` in that sense.

Answer (score 3):

For me the solution was:

1) You must import `polyglossia` *first*
2) Next, import `textenc`
3) Finally, you can import `times`

For example:

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}  % For typesetting various languages in UTF-8 including Bengali
\setmainlanguage{english}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{times,latexsym}
```